# I have some pod files and a makefile and I need to generate a PDF, how to do it?

Tags: unix, pdf, latex

I inherited some *.pod files and a makefile which looks like this:

```
all:mypdf.pdf mypdf2.pdf

#pod2latex files/*.pod
#pod_tools/list2latex.pl > pod_files.tex
#pdflatex reference
```

I'm on a Windows machine and I would need to regenerate this pdf. Since I've never done this before, how should I proceed? What are those pod files?

Any steps to follow to generate my pdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). Select for installation the packages that include the required commands and then you can run `make`.